# How to disable OpenSC YubiKey password prompt in Firefox

Tags: firefox, security, prompt, yubikey, opensc

I have a YubiKey nano plugged into a 2019 MacBook Pro.

When I visit some websites (one public example being Gmail), Firefox brings up a password dialog prompting me to enter the YubiKey password.  Gmail has nothing to do with my YubiKey.  Also, I don't even have the password because my organization does not give us the master key to our YubiKeys.

```
Password Required - Mozilla Firefox

Please enter the password for the PKCS#11 token

YK-XXX-XXX ..
```

[image: Password Required -]

The only slightly informative additional avenue I've discovered is to go to Settings -> Security Devices and view the OpenSC device information (See the two bottom images).

Is there a way to disable the prompt?

I don't want to ditch Firefox, but this is a daily annoyance and I have googled the subject extensively and feel like I must be missing something!

[image: Settings -> Security Devices -> OpenSC]

[image: Settings -> Security Devices -> OpenSC -> Yubico Yubikey]

Comment: For what purpose is the YubiKey used? For WebAuthn no plugin should be required not sure about TOTP. So may be you can disable the plugin?

Comment: If there are no other smartcards you use with Firefox, you could click the "Unload" button to not use the OpenSC module. (You can also load it back in if really needed.) 

The Yubikey can be used in three ways: OTP, FIDO and CCID(Smart card). Your organization may not have have set up the Yubikey as a PKCS11 smartcard.
On the page before "Device Manager" click on "View Certificates..." If there are none listed (and they did not give you a PIN for the card, then for sure you do not to load the OpenSC module.

Answer (score 1):

On the Security Devices Page (Which you can find by clicking on settings and then searching for "Security Devices"), find the OpenSC library and then click unload. This will remove it until you manually re-add the library.

To re-add the library find the path to the opensc library. On (Most) Linux distributions that is /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so. Click Load, specify the correct path (possibly above), and supply an informative name and you are back in action.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the opensc package was installed long ago and wasn't required, so I uninstalled it and resolved this annoyance.

Sorry, this doesn't answer the question if you have to use opensc for something else, but at least a second thought to check if you really need that package.